# Moving objects in code updates their position in the 3d viewer, but snaps it back to starting location when a keyframe is added

Tags: python

I am using an Xbox One controller to move objects up and down on the Z axis for the purpose of creating a puppet style rig for auto keying. Everything works as intended in the 3d viewer with the objects moving up and down with the controller axes until I add another keyframe. At that point all the objects snap back to their starting point. I think that this is because the objects never really update their position, before the next keyframe. I tried using  obj.matrix_world = obj.matrix_basis after every location change, but I did not see any difference. Ideally, I turn on auto Keying, hit the play button, and blender records every selected objects movements. My end goal is to make pretty complex puppeteering rigs.

````
import bpy
import XInput

class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs itself from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}
    
        #controller Code
        state=XInput.get_state(0)
        
        LSDown = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
        
        LT = bpy.data.objects["Empty"]
        
        LSDown.location[2] = XInput.get_thumb_values(state)[1][1]*-1
        LSDown.matrix_world = LSDown.matrix_basis      
        LT.location[2] = XInput.get_trigger_values(state)[0]
        LT.matrix_world = LT.matrix_basis
#        if XInput.get_button_values(state)['RIGHT_SHOULDER']:
#            bpy.context.scene.frame_set(bpy.context.scene.frame_current +1) 

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ModalTimerOperator.bl_idname, text=ModalTimerOperator.bl_label)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.append(menu_func)


# Register and add to the "view" menu (required to also use F3 search "Modal Timer Operator" for quick access).
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_view.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```
````